# Swift protocol method conflicts with superclass property

Tags: macos, swift, protocols, subclass

I’m trying to subclass `NSColorPicker` and adopt the `NSColorPickingCustom` protocol.

`NSColorPicker` has some simple computed properties like

```
var buttonToolTip: String { get }
```

But `NSColorPickingCustom` requires methods with the same name, like

```
func buttonToolTip() -> String
```

If I implement the method `buttonToolTop`, it conflicts with the superclass getter with the same name. If I override the computed property, I'm not conforming to the protocol. If I try using *both* then of course they conflict with each other.

Is there any way for a class to adopt that protocol while subclassing `NSColorPicker`?

Comment: Why do you need to do both? Wouldn't *either* subclassing or implementing the protocol be enough?

Comment: NSColorPicker already provides the NSColorPickingDefault conformance for you (which is where the `buttonToolTip()` requirement seems to be). Overriding just the computed property seems to be fine.

Comment: @jtbandes is exactly right. `var buttonToolTip` has a getter; that getter _is_ the equivalent of the `func buttonToolTip()` that NSColorPickingCustom is looking for.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen my understanding is that a custom color picker needs to have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSColorPicker` already provides the `NSColorPickingDefault` conformance for you (which is where the `buttonToolTip()` requirement seems to be coming from). Overriding just the computed property seems to work fine:

```
import Cocoa

class C: NSColorPicker, NSColorPickingCustom
{
    override var buttonToolTip: String { return "test" }

    // NSColorPickingCustom
    func supportsMode(mode: NSColorPanelMode) -> Bool { return false }
    func currentMode() -> NSColorPanelMode { return .NSNoModeColorPanel }
    func provideNewView(initialRequest: Bool) -> NSView { return NSView() }
    func setColor(newColor: NSColor) { }
}

let c = C()
c.buttonToolTip // returns "test"

let d: NSColorPickingDefault = C()
d.buttonToolTip() // returns "test"
```

Comment: Not just "seems". That is the _nature_ of a computed variable. Its getter _is_ the eponymous function (as far as Objective-C is concerned). Swift cannot see it that way, because the explicit getter is automatically suppressed; but Objective-C does see it that way. A read-only property, to Objective-C, is merely a shorthand for the existence of the getter.

Comment: Right, *as far as Objective-C is concerned*. In Swift, of course, the syntax is different for functions and computed properties, but `@property NSString *buttonToolTip;` implies `- (NSString *)buttonToolTip`.

Comment: And the fact `func buttonToolTip()` shows up at all is just a weirdness of the bridging of Obj-C to Swift. @TomHarrington, I would recommend [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: That's very strange because when I do the same thing, the compiler complains that my class doesn't conform because `protocol requires function 'buttonToolTip()' with type '() -> String'`. I had already tried what you show but for some reason it doesn't work here. I'm using Swift 1.2, not sure what version you have.

Comment: @TomHarrington What happens if you explicitly give your setter the name `buttonToolTip` with `@objc(buttonToolTip)`?

Comment: @jtbandes Your answer suggests it should just work, but you also suggest filing a bug? I'm not sure what to think. I don't mind filing, but if I can get it to work like you do I'd prefer that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Swift 2 where it works fine. (Even though it works, I think it's a bug that the same property is exposed in 2 different ways.) Do you need to declare the conformance? It may be easiest to just avoid NSColorPickingCustom.

Comment: The docs say that the protocol is required for custom color pickers. "It works in Swift 2" is a good answer though, as I can probably just use 2 on this project. Thanks.